# Need to remove trailing .000 in sql output file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I have this query, and in the table/column ttransactionlog_1/occurdatetime, it returns the time value with a .000 at the end, can someone tell me how to remove that from each row? here is a line from the outputfile showing the .000 at the end of the time

```
0,112213,2021-03-11 14:00:00.000,Santiago,Melody,AdminClock.
```

Here is the query:

```
sqlcmd -S clock\punch -d test -U xxx -P xxxxx -Q "Select Distinct TTransactionLog_1.DecisionTimeInterval, TTransactionLog_1.UserID, TTransactionLog_1.OccurDateTime, TTransactionLog_1.lastname, TTransactionLog_1.firstname, TSystemLog1.Name
From TTransactionLog_1 Inner join TSystemLog1 On TTransactionLog_1.NodeID=TSystemLog1.NodeID where TSystemLog1.NodeID = 3  and TTransactionLog_1.OccurDateTime > = dateadd(hh, -1, getdate())   
" -s "," -h-1 -W -o "C:\ATR\adminreport.csv"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: `cast(MyValue as datetime2(0))`

Comment: jarlh, it does matter, this output file will get uploaded to an i series main frame and the format, character count, etc,,, has to be exact.

Comment: Dale K, thank you, I will try that shortly.

Comment: Or look at the `format()` function. The official documentation should always be your first port of call.

Comment: `select distinct` on a joined query is a code smell. Usually indicates a problem with the join

Answer (score 0):

Does just using `Convert` on the `OccurDateTime` value work for you?

Example

```
declare @OccurDateTime datetime='20210311 14:00:00.000'

select Convert(varchar(19),@OccurDateTime,121)
```